# Convert spaces&tabs line's indentation to tabs using a single regex

Tags: python, regex, replace, sublimetext3, pcre

I want to convert all indentation in the text with only tabs using a single regex.

The regex I'm using is:

```
(?<=\n)((?:\t)|(?:\t\t)|(?:\t\t\t)|(?:\t\t\t\t)|(?:\t\t\t\t\t)|(?:\t\t\t\t\t\t)|(?:\t\t\t\t\t\t\t)|(?:\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t)|(?:\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t)|(?:\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t))?((?:    )|(?:   \t)|(?:  \t)|(?: \t))+?
```

Replace with:

```
$1\t
```

Original text:
[image]
Note that the indentation is made of spaces and/or tabs.

Desired text:
[image]

***The problem is that my regex works only for one substitution***, as you can see here:
[image]

I put the rule `(?<=\n)` in front of the regex to match only the line after the newline character `\n` to avoid the regex to match the middle-line text.

How to modify the regex to replace **each** occurrence of `((?:    )|(?:   \t)|(?:  \t)|(?: \t))` with one `\t`?

[Online demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gkeBQo/2)

Thanks a lot.

Ps. I think that the syntax must be for python because I'll use it in SublimeText3.

Comment: Sorry what's the rule in plain English? Why doesn't the first line get changed?

Comment: because there isn't a `\n` before it.

Comment: So you want to replace all tab/space sequences between an `\n` and a non-tab/space character with tabs? How many tabs?

Comment: Correct, infinite tabs/spaces mantaining the indentation correct. So `   \t` must be converted in `\t`

Comment: And a sequence of four spaces gets converted to a tab, whereas less than four spaces gets removed? Is that a full description of the behaviour?

Comment: See the image desired text in my post.

Comment: I mean that visually the position of the text "Replace the text before me" does not change. I need it in PHP scripts when there are e.g. `function name()\n{...}`

Comment: "Visually it does not change" is not a sufficiently precise description. We don't know how whatever you're talking about behaves visually so we can't answer. You need to tell us how many spaces is equivalent to a tab. It looks like four. Is that correct or not?

Comment: @Denziloe see the image "Desired text:". Every "space-space-space-tab", "space-space-tab", "space-tab" must be converted in single tab. But starting from the left of the line, so doing that the whole indentation become made with only tabs and visually it does not change in the IDE.